# Text Fadein/Fadeout at Random Positions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to put together a webpage that has text that pops up at random locations on the page, fade out, then appear again at a random location again. I found something that suits my purposes for example. I want something like this, but with text that I can manipulate and make a list out of with text-shadow effects if needed.

```
(function makeDiv(){
var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
$newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
    'width':divsize+'px',
    'height':divsize+'px',
    'background-color': color
});

var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

$newdiv.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px',
    'display':'none'
}).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100).delay(300).fadeOut(200, function(){
   $(this).remove();
   makeDiv(); 
});
```

})();

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redler/QcUPk/8/)

This is a second example of something similar, only it doesn't have random position.

```
$('li').each(function(){
var randomTop = $('div').height()*Math.random(); //random top position
var randomLeft = $('div').width()*Math.random(); //random left position

$(this).css({ //apply the position each li
        top        : randomTop,
        left    : randomLeft
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4pxq/9/)

I'm hoping to sort of splice the two together in order to get what I'm ideally looking for. Please forget the formatting as its my first time here and I'm trying to conform to the standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're looking for but I "spliced them together."

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4pxq/123/)

```
(function fadeInDiv(){
    var divs = $('.fadeIn');
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var maxSize = 30;
    var minSize = 8;
    var size = (Math.random()*maxSize+minSize)

    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*divs.length));

    if (!elem.is(':visible')){
        elem.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),fadeInDiv);
        elem.css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'left':posx+'px',
            'top':posy+'px',
            'font-size': size+'px'
        });
    } else {
        elem.fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),fadeInDiv); 
    }
})();
```

EDIT: Updated Fiddle URL

Comment: That is absolutely perfect. Thank you very very much for that!